# Automatic flag(s) on large number of edit rejections

Tags: support

There is a particular user submitting a large number of edits, half of which at least are invalid. Is the large number of rejected edits raising any automatic flags to the moderators? Or should these cases be reported manually?

Answer (score 4):

There are [automatic bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91392/270345) - but the edit should be rejected. It may happen that you reject it, but two others accept it - and your rejection won't count (at least, as far as I can tell).